# JMeter Shuts down the run after certain period

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am new to JMeter.

I got 30 APIs and want to perform load run for 50 users.

I am using the ultimate thread group. Below is my configuration.

Thread count: 50
Initial delay : 0
Startup:60
Hold for:1800
Shutdown: 60

When I initiate runs I don't find any issues. But after certain minutes JMeter stops running. can I know why it happens like this and what can I do to skip the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your "stops running" statement is not too informative hence we cannot help without knowing all the details.

If something goes wrong with JMeter take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it contains sufficient information to guess the cause of the problem, it is also possible to increase log level for the whole application or for individual components. See [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for details.

Also a common mistake of those who are "new to JMeter" is running load test from JMeter GUI, if this is your case - remember that GUI is only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution [you should be using command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with all Listeners disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I run it from Command-line how to capture the metrics. I want to capture Average Time, 95%, Throughput, and error % with which listener can I capture all these. Can you please help me

Comment: Else, please let me know/correct me what all metrics are important to submit to the client after load run